# Is there a name for the function $1 / (1 + x)$?

Tags: functions, notation, terminology

Does the function

$$f(x) = \frac{1}{1  + x}$$

have a recognizable name?

For example a related function with a recognizable name is the *logistic function*, defined by:

$$l(x) = \frac{1}{1  + e^{-x}}$$

**Note:** By the way I am quite happy with functions without name.... except when I have to write code for a program, then I wish for nice names.

Comment: Suggestion: we call $f$ the Fred-function.

Comment: I am happy that not every function has a name. Otherwise Mathematics would have scared me off :-).

Comment: https://www.geogebra.org/m/JMVCbBjQ

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy: there are uncountably many different functions, so not all can get a name. You are safe forever.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a *homographic function*.

As a curve, it is also an *equilateral hyperbola*.

Comment: These are *properties* of the function, but they are not names of it because there are many other functions to which they apply. You could also say this is a *rational* function, an *analytic* function, and many other adjectives...

Comment: @Rahul: I disagree. When you say "an *exponential* function", you unambiguously mean a function of the form $ab^x$. This is not a property. You will find many posts about *the* homographic function.

Comment: Fair enough. Upon further consideration the boundary between "name" and "property" is a bit fuzzy; answering "what is the name of the function $3x^2+2x+5$?" with "it is a quadratic polynomial" feels unsatisfactory, but answering "what is the name of the shape $(x-3)^2+(y-2)^2=5^2$?" with "it is a circle" feels perfectly correct.

Comment: @Rahul: I also made the distinction between the function and the curve. I (personally) would call $3x^2+2x+5$ a quadratic function and wouldn't be bothered by a *parabolic* function.

Comment: @Rahul: I (still personally) consider that $x$ and/or $y$ translations and/or scalings do not change the nature of the function (say a *linear* function or a *sinusoid*). And curves are invariant to similarity transforms (but not necessarily to general affinities).